# How to get exit code of remote command through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am running a script from remote machine via ssh:

```
ssh 'some_cmd;my_script'
```

Now, I want to store exit status of shell script on my local machine. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Could you explain some more details? The command is started from _remote_ and running on _local_?

Comment: from man ssh: EXIT STATUS
     ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

Answer (score 26):

Assuming nothing goes wrong with `ssh` itself, its exit status is the exit status of the last command executed on the remote host. (If something *does* go wrong, its exit status is 255.)

```
$ ssh remotehost exit 13
$ echo $?
13
```

Comment: Formally, to "store" the exit status we should assign it to a variable: `ssh remotehost 'do something' ; retcode=$?` and it's "stored" in $retcode

Comment: Right; I missed the "store" aspect of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer which helped me a lot, and +1. However, could you please shortly tell us what you think about the following article: https://www.osetc.com/en/how-to-check-the-exit-status-from-a-ssh-remote-command-in-linux-bash.html The author claims that there are a lot of values reserved as exit codes of SSH itself (not only the value 255).

Comment: I am not sure where the author got that list; it's not in the man page on the machines I've checked. Part of the problem is that the exit status is ambiguous in this situation: did `ssh` itself have a problem, or did the program that `ssh` ran have one of those exit statuses?

Comment: Indeed ... this just doesn't cater well for the corner case where the remote exit code equals `255` .... other than that a great answer :)

Comment: This is not true for the ssh client coming with FreeBSD 11.1.

Comment: This did not work for me on macOS 12.6.2 with SSH version: `ssh -V`: `OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6`.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I don't think the previous answers will work (at least, they did not work for me).

This is what worked for me: I ran my command and displayed the exit code and captured it in a variable.

Ensure you protect the `$?` sign with the escape sequence, `\`:

```
# retcode=$(ssh test@1.2.3.4 "grep -q test /etc/passwd ; echo \$? " 2>/dev/null)
# echo $retcode
# 1
```