# How to overwrite a local bash script variable over ssh connection?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a command in a remote machine and overwrite my local bash script variable with this exit code.
something like this:

```
ret=0
ssh -T user@192.168.10.1 <<- EOSSH
cat / #This line will return an exit code 1
ret=$(( $ret|$? )
EOSSH

echo $ret #This variable print 0, but I want that print 1 because of the exit code
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Mind, the ssh command itself will have a `$?` reflecting the exit status of the command it ran remotely.

Comment: You ask how to set variables generally, but in your specific case you can more easily get [the exit code via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701143/how-to-get-exit-code-of-remote-command-through-ssh)